# Notfication start the intent without clicking and doesn't shows in the top

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

this is my code of the notfication:

```
private void DrawNotfication(Context context) {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        File xlsx = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "test.xlsx");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(xlsx);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Application available to view XLS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        PendingIntent ped = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("content")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(ped)
                .build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

for some reason when it show the notification it starts the intent before I click it.. And also it doesn't appears in the top of the screen..

how can I fix it?

thanks!!

Comment: For example: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: @Yupi I saw this already.. this is exactly what I did but it still not working

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent);`